# Wifi CA Certificates disappearing

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, sony-xperia, certificates

I have an Xperia E3 running 4.4.2. My university's wifi network has a CA certificate to avoid having to re-enter credentials each time you connect. However, whenever I install this certificate (and select it for that network) it disappears after having been used once or twice, so I have to re-install it every few days. To clarify, when I go to "modify network" the CA certificate disappears from the drop-down menu, and it also disappears from my list of trusted credentials.

Is there a way to keep it permanently instead of having to re-install all the time?

Comment: I get vaguely the same on my galaxy A5 (4.4.4), although in my case it doesn't disappear off the list of trusted credentials but disappears off the network drop down menu.

Comment: I get this problem too, but for an 802.1x-protected network that uses SIM for authentication. Very frustrating!

Comment: I had this problem, then I noticed that the user certificate file I was provided also contains the CA, and selecting that "user" certificate for both the CA and User fields worked. If that isn't the case for you, maybe try creating a single combined file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/19721047/12033212) and using that?